# what is the difference between the hosts and hosts.allow files?

Tags: networking, server, hosts

what is the difference between the hosts and hosts.allow files?  From what I have read it seems like both files are for adding IP address allowing network access.

Below are my hosts and hosts.allow files:

```
/etc/hosts  
127.0.0.1   localhost  
127.0.1.1   craig-PE-T130

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts  
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback


/etc/hosts.allow  
list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).

Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_netgroup
            ALL: .foobar.edu EXCEPT terminalserver.foobar.edu
            If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
            daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are quite different in their functions.

1. `/etc/hosts` is used as a local DNS on your local `apache` instance or `nginx` as the case may be to mapped `domain names` to the `ip address 127.0.*.*`.

   ```
   From "man hosts": hosts - static table lookup for hostnames. So when we request a domain 
   in our browser say "mydoman.com", our system checks in the /etc/hosts files to resolve 
   this "domain name" to an "IP address". If we have that entry in the "/etc/hosts" file
   then the page content is served up from our machine files else it look out on the inter-
   net to resolve that name.
   ```
2. `/etc/host.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` is used like an `iptable` to control access to the machine or network form external sources. Note that *both iptables and host access* can't be used simultaneously. Its your either using `iptables` host access control mechanism, or your using the `access control library` mechanism

   ```
   Example hosts file entries are

   #
   # hosts.allow   This file describes the names of 
   #               the hosts that are allowed to use 
   #               the local INET services, as decided
   #               by the '/usr/sbin/tcpd' server.
   #
   # Only allow connections within the virginia.edu 
   # domain.

   ALL: .virginia.edu


   #
   # hosts.deny    This file describes the names of
   #               the hosts that are *not* allowed 
   #               to use the local INET services, as 
   #               decided by the '/usr/sbin/tcpd' 
   #               server.
   #
   # deny all by default, only allowing hosts or 
   # domains listed in hosts.allow.

   ALL: ALL
   ```

Sources:

man hosts, man hosts_access, [virginia.edu](http://its.virginia.edu/unixsys/sec/hosts.html)

Comment: How one chooses to use iptables or host access? Is installing/uninstalling iptables enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/hosts
```

Is a file that will permit name resolution on the local host. Taking the Ipv4 or IPv6 address and translating it to a friendly name.

```
/etc/hosts.allow
```

Is used by `XDCMP` protocol to provide a list of permitted machines to access the service.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
etc/hosts
```

file is used to associate domain names to IP addresses. An entry for an IP address is given in a single line. 
In today's systems, etc/hosts file (also called the host table) is suppressed by the DNS server. I use it mainly for local testing. It is a common part of an operating system's Internet Protocol (IP) implementation.

The

```
etc/hosts.allow or etc/hosts.deny
```

is used to allow/deny access to different services.

Generally, these files are deprecated these days. If you want to block access to a service by this way, you need to find whether that service has been compiled with TCP Wrappers or not. Firewall is a good way to block services.